# How to connect two monitors to a DELL Inspiron 5520 15R

Tags: laptop, display, external-display, dell-inspiron

I have a DELL 5520 notebook. The machine has two graphic cards working together (intel 4000 and radeon 7670).
I'm trying to connect it to two external monitors. I also tried to set it up to 1 monitor and 1 TV at the same time. The result is the same 2 out of 3 are working.

So, i'm connecting the monitors to VGA and HDMI port. However only one of them is working or in the case that i close the lid of the notebook, then the 2 externals are on.

In the company there are guys which already set their laptops with two monitors without external hardware and they gave it a shot, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

P.S. It's a DELL Inspiron 5520 15R (i7 version).
Apparently it's not US spec, so it HAS intel 4000 gpu and it HAS Radeon 7670.

Comment: So is it a `Dell Inspiron 15R 5520` or a `Dell Latitude E5520` ?

Comment: It's Inspiron 15R

Answer (score 3):

- Here are the specifications for the [Dell Inspiron 15R 5520](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15r-5520/pd) (All Models)
- The New Inspiron 15R Special Edition has an AMD Radeon™ HD 7730M 2GB, but again that's all it has. Does **NOT** have two cards.
- Your laptop does **NOT** have 2 graphics cards.
- And when you run a monitor on VGA (Analog) and HDMI (Digital) any one can run at a given time. Analog and Digital will not run at the same time. More information [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/449839-can-i-use-vga-out-hdmi-out-same-time.html).
- You will need external hardware to run it simultaneously.

Comment: Well, the processor comes with intel 4000 gpu. Check [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/67356).

Comment: So basically your on Intel 4000 Integrated Graphics. And you cant run analog and digital , ie: VGA and HDMI at the same time.

Comment: Apparently it's not US spec, so it HAS intel 4000 gpu and it HAS Radeon 7670.

Comment: send me ur localized spec link.

Comment: [It's in Bulgarian](http://laptop.bg/laptops-dell-Inspiron_5520_Switch-dell_inspiron_5520_5397063187836)

Comment: `AMD Radeon 7670M с 1 GB DDR 3 собствена памет` right? Still there is only 1 Graphics card, and still the same logic applies either VGA or HDMI. If u had a DVI and HDMI it would have worked as both would have been digital. Btw, a pro laptop guy says, it will still work on Intel 3000/4000, and there is no way to swap between the two adapters. Here is the link : http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120829001536AANMnuX

Comment: Thanks for your effort man. I will go ahead and test once again.