# Inspiron 15SE laptop and two monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dell-inspiron, docking-station

I have seen this question [How to connect two monitors to a DELL Inspiron 5520 15R](https://superuser.com/questions/468513/how-to-connect-two-monitors-to-a-dell-inspiron-5520-15r) and I am aware that it is possible that the 15R does not have the ability to connect to two  monitors at the same time.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this with the help of some external hardware? I would prefer buying a decent docking station (that way it can be reused for other laptops) but can you please answer the following specific questions

1. Links to docking stations (do I buy Dell?) that are compatible with Dell Inspiron 15R
2. What attributes do I look for  in a Docking station? I am new to this so I know that a docking station can be used to connect multiple monitors but are there any other things that I should look out for?

Comment: I was able to find a docking station by doing a Google search for "dell inspiron 15r 5520 docking station" based on the questions asked it doesn't seem you have done any research. Of course it appears that Dell doesn't make a docking station for this laptop and of the two supported docking stations that exist the only one that does video only supoprts a single Video input.  In other words your laptop does not support two monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can achieve this with the help of some external hardware?

You know your laptop has one external monitor connection.  You know that if you get a docking station, you *still* will only have one external monitor connection.  So, don't bother with the docking station.

Since you have no problem with purchasing extra hardware, just buy a [USB video adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20video%20adapter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=usb%20video%20adapter&client=firefox-a&hs=USX&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=CruKUcKLAdS84APZqoGgAg&ved=0CDwQsxg&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46226182,d.dmg&fp=7341d7bfb0a054d8&biw=1276&bih=629).  Spend $40 to $50 and you will be all set.  You can then use the External monitor connection, and the USB video adapter to connect two monitors.

Comment: Ah I assumed that Docking stations automatically give me the ability to connect multiple monitors. Now I know that is not the case. Let me look at the USB video adapter a bit more detail. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any instructions on how to make this work so that my setup looks like http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/customer-media/product-gallery/B005G306I2/ref=cm_ciu_pdp_images_0?ie=UTF8&index=0? I assume connect one monitor using Laptop HDMI, another monitor by using the startech cable which is connected to laptop USB and monitor(? how is it connected to the monitor?)

Comment: I don't know how it is connected to the monitor, because you haven't purchased anything.  You asked how it was possible.  If you want to connect via HDMI, you can purchase a USB to HDMI instead of one that only has a VGA.  How would you set that up?  Place two monitors side by side.  Connect one monitor to laptop external monitor port.  Connect other monitor to USB video adapter.  Connect external keyboard and mouse.